# Gantry 5 Extended Style menu dropdown onclick to hover

Tags: javascript, css, joomla, hover, gantry-framework

When having a Gantry menu set at Extended style with menu-item1 > menu-item2 > menu-item3 , the dropdown of the item2 to show item3 requires the user to click on the arrow to expand. How do you make it function on hover.

I'm afraid users won't know to click on the arrow to expand the menu. Is there a way to use the extended styling and change the onclick function with hover or both?

Saw this javascript solution from Stackoverflow for both functions.

```
var hoverOrClick = function () {
    // do something common
}
$('#target').click(hoverOrClick).hover(hoverOrClick);
```

Could the above work with the media/gantry5/assests/js/main.js is the file controlling this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla Admin go to Components > Gantry5 Themes. Then in the right corner click on the "Menu" button, select menu which you want to use hover function and click on its cog wheel icon. In its settings just uncheck "Disable dropdowns".

Comment: If you are able to provide Joomla support, please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.